# Is this a valid proof? (Finite and infinite sets)

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Thm: Let $A, B$ be sets. If $A$ is finite and $B \subseteq A$, then $B $ is also finite, and $|B| \le |A|$. Furthermore, if $B\not=A$ then $|B| < |A|$.

Proof: Assume $A$ is finite and $B\subseteq A$. Since $A$ is finite, there exists some $n \in \Bbb {N}$ such that $I_n \sim A$. Since $A$ is finite and $B \subseteq A$, it follows that $B$ is finite. Since $B \subseteq A$, either $B=A$ or $B\not=A$. If $B=A$, then $I_n \sim B$ and it follows that $|A|=n=|B|$. If $B\not=A$, then $B\subset A$, and it follows that $|B|<|A|=n$.

Is this the correct way to go about a proof like this? If not, what approach should I take. If so, am I leaving anything vital out?

Comment: It seems like you are assuming what you have to prove.

Comment: This is what it felt like, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try constructing a bijection from $B$ to some $I_n$. How this can be achieved really depends on your foundations.

Comment: @SBareS can point out an example of something I've assumed that I should not have been able to that makes the bijection construction necessary? While the proof I posted feels like it flows a bit too easily, It still looks like every step follows from a definition.

Comment: You actually assumed every part of the theorem. You assumed that $B\subseteq A$ implies $B$ is finite, and that $|B| \ne |A|$ implies $|B| < |A|$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where your proof goes off the rails:

> Since $A$ is finite and $B \subseteq A$, it follows that $B$ is finite.

Another problem is here:

> If $B\neq A,$ then ... it follows that $|B|<|A|.$

In other words, you're saying "If the premises of the Theorem I'm currently trying to prove are true, then the conclusion of said Theorem is true, too." While this is correct, it is not allowable in a proof of that Theorem, as it constitutes circular reasoning.

You got off to a good start, though! You've concluded that $I_n\sim A$ for some $n\in\Bbb N.$ Now, to show that $B$ is finite, one way we can go is to show that $I_m\sim B$ for some $m\in\Bbb N;$ moreover, you'd like to show that if $B\neq A,$ then $m<n.$ Another thing to keep in mind is that if $B=A,$ then we don't *have* to prove that $B$ is finite, since we've assumed it! Thus, we need only address the case that $B\neq A.$

First, we note that if $B=\emptyset,$ then $B=I_0,$ so we're done. Hence, we may assume that $B\neq\emptyset.$ Since $I_n\sim A,$ then you should be able to prove (or directly conclude) that there is a bijection $f:A\to I_n.$ Let $g:B\to I_n$ be defined by $g(b)=f(b)$ for all $b\in B.$ (Do you see why we can do this?) You should be able to prove that $g$ is an injection, but *not* a surjection. In other words, there are some "gaps" in the range of $g$ in the codomain $I_n.$ Since we're trying to find a bijection $B\to I_m$ for some $m\in\Bbb N,$ then one approach we can take is to "fill in" those gaps. In particular, we could let $C$ be the range of $g,$ and define $h:C\to I_n$ recursively as follows:

> $h(\min C):=\min I_n,$ and if $y$ is the least $x\in C$ for which we haven't yet defined $h(x),$ then we let $h(y):=\min\bigl\{k\in I_n:(x\in C\text{ and }x<y)\implies h(x)<k\bigr\}.$

You'll then have to prove that $h:C\to I_n$ is a well-defined injection, but not a surjection. Moreover, you should show that the range of $h$ is $I_m$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$ with $m<n.$ Finally, prove that $h\circ g:B\to I_m$ is the desired bijection.